# How do I run REACT JS on XAMPP apache localhost?

Tags: reactjs, xampp, localhost

**I am a beginner at a very basic level.** I am doing a project with React JS for the frontend and PHP for the backend. I want them both to run on the same localhost. *How to
*run react on the XAMPP localhost*?*  I am not very much familiar with both the languages, it would be helpful if the process is as simple as possible.

Comment: you must build the react app then you can host it on xampp. or use proxypass for development

Comment: if you want it to be simple stick to using `create-react-app`, you can also run xampp at the same time, no worries they will both be in localhost but using different ports. for instance react default port is localhost:3000 and xampp will use another port..